# How to select two area in map using html

Tags: html, css

is there any way to select two **area map** using html **"COORDS"** in one click

**for exemple:**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div class="map">
<MAP name="map1">
<AREA 
HREF="#"
SHAPE="poly"
ALT=""
COORDS="85,6,85,7,84,7..."/>
<AREA 
HREF="#"
SHAPE="poly"
ALT=""
COORDS="90,60,55,7,94,28..."/>
</Map>
<IMG SRC="France.png" USEMAP="#map1" />
    
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

i want to select this two **AREA** in one click

Comment: Can you link to a working image as `france.png` doesn't link to any real image - so we can better understand your goal?

Comment: Those AREA tags are for creating a clickable area on an image. What do you mean by "select"?

Comment: @dehart i mean when i click one of those erea the two show as selected and not the only one that i have clicked

Answer (score 0):

HTML can only focus 1 element at the time. You can add a class to multiple `<area>` elements and style them to look selected.

In below example, I add a click event handler to the`<map>` element.
The listener will loop through the `<area>` elements inside the `<map>` remove the class name of each item and set the `className` to "selected" if the `href` attribute matches with the clicked target.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<style>map .selected { border:1px dashed green; }</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="map">
<MAP id="map1" name="map1">
<AREA HREF="#" SHAPE="poly" ALT="" COORDS="85,6,85,7,84,7..."/>
<AREA HREF="#" SHAPE="poly" ALT="" COORDS="90,60,55,7,94,28..."/>
</Map>
<IMG SRC="France.png" USEMAP="#map1" />
    
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
var map = document.selectElementById('map1");
map.addEventListener('click',function(event) {
    var t = event.target;
    for(var i = 0; i < map.children.length; i++) {
       map.children[i].className = '';
       if(t.href == map.children[i].href)
           map.children[i].className = 'selected';
    }
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```